# how to solve nested columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am w trying to build a page structure using bootstrap but running into couple of issue.

I have a left container that that is holding some columns and a right container that is holding some other columns.

the problem i have is the the 4 small boxes running across the page in the left container have margin pushing them in left and right. the 4 boxes need to be inline with the other top panel.

Also when i change the screen width the 4 boxes dont keep to 4 boxes they push out huge, 
is there a good way to have them respond less aggressive?

Please see my [fiddle attached](http://jsfiddle.net/hLGhu/)

```
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 hero-feature">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Feature Label</h3>
                <p>This would be a great spot to feature some brand new products!</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your four nested columns are indented further than the panel above it is because you didn't wrap the nested columns in a `div.row` class.

[Updated jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hLGhu/1/).

Part two of your question has to do with the classes you are using in respect to BS3. I would try the following and see if it yields a better response:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Feature Label</h3>
      <p>This would be a great spot to feature some brand new products!</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a></p>
    </div> <!-- /.caption -->
  </div> <!-- /.thumbnail -->
</div> <!-- /.col-lg-3.col-sm-6.hero-feature or nested column -->
```

Notice the class change from `.col-md-6` to `.col-sm-6`.

Also, if you want your main container to not wrap so quickly, try replacing `.col-lg-10` to `.col-md-10` or `.col-sm-10`. Update your sidebar as well, replacing `.col-lg-2` with `.col-md-10` or `.col-sm-10`, whichever size you decide on going.

[jsFiddle for different container sizes](http://jsfiddle.net/hLGhu/3/).